# Does Google Backup "phone home" even when disabled?

Tags: privacy, google-backup

I was just giving [viaProtect](http://www.appbrain.com/app/viaprotect-%28public-preview%29/com.viaforensics.viaprotect.android.agent) a try, and stumbled upon this:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>viaProtect Screenshot showing "phone-home" activities (click image to enlarge)</sup>

As you can see in the highlighted area, `SystemBackupService` is contacting something in the US. Sure, that could be Google Cloud backup backing up my apps, settings, whatsnot. But the thing is: I've turned that off from the beginning (on account initialization, I've answered the question for "Do you want to backup..." with a clear "No"). So I'd not even expect the service running at all, not to speak of transferring data to any place.

Am I missing something here? I first thought the same service might be used to sync contacts/calendars as well. But then I saw the other entry "3 lines up": "Google-Kontakte synchronisieren" (Google contacts sync), so that's a separate service.

I don't like being spied upon without my consent. And I don't want my data going to the cloud without being able to control *what exactly* goes there (most stuff I don't want there at all). So what's wrong here? And how do I stop that (except by flashing a custom ROM with no GApps, or removing/freezing them all, I mean ;)?